# Kivy Issue updating spinner values based off other spinner selection (navigating file directory)

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm currently building an app that creates some "media" that is then is submitted into a file directory.
In the submission screen I have 4 spinners on top of each other (project, level, room, category)
what I'm trying to achieve is say when the **project** spinner is set to 'project 1' the **level** spinner values self populate to all the files within the project 1 folder. then once the level spinner is selected the room spinner values self populate and so on.

here's how I'm currently doing that:

.py file

```
def update_project_spinner(self):
    folderContents = os.listdir(DataBasePath)
    values = folderContents[1:]
    values.sort()
    return values

def update_level_spinner(self, value):
    folderLocation = DataBasePath + '/' + self.ids.project_spinner_id.text
    folderContents = os.listdir(folderLocation)
    values = folderContents[1:]
    values.sort()
    print(values)
    return values
```

.kv file

```
Spinner:
        text: "Project"
        size_hint_x: 1
        size_hint_y: 0.5
        values: root.update_project_spinner()
        id: project_spinner_id
        on_text:
            root.project_spinner_clicked(project_spinner_id.text)
            root.update_level_spinner()
    GridLayout:
        size_hint_x: 1
        size_hint_y: 0.5
        cols: 2
        Spinner:
            text: "Level"
            size_hint_x: 1
            size_hint_y: 1
            values: root.update_level_spinner()
            id: level_spinner_id
            on_text: root.level_spinner_clicked(level_spinner_id.text)
                     root.update_room_spinner()
        Spinner:
            text: "Room"
            size_hint_x: 1
            size_hint_y: 1
            values: root.update_room_spinner()
            id: room_spinner_id
            on_text: root.room_spinner_clicked(room_spinner_id.text)
                     root.update_category_spinner()

    Spinner:
        text: "Category"
        size_hint_x: 1
        size_hint_y: 0.5
        values: root.update_category_spinner()
        id: category_spinner_id
        on_text: root.category_spinner_clicked(category_spinner_id.text)
```

The projects spinner works fine as its value are set at build, its the other spinners that need to be updated I'm having trouble with. I don't seem to have an issue changing the data in values but it doesn't update on the gui, but id really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't actually doing anything to update the gui. Try adding:

```
    self.ids.level_spinner_id.values = values
```

to the end of the `update_level_spinner` method.

Another way is to create a `ListProperty` of levels in the containing class and use that in the `kv` as:

```
values: root.levels
```

Then the `update_level_spinner` method can simply update the `ListProperty` like:

```
self.levels = values
```

at the end of the `update_level_spinner` method.

Comment: using the ListProperty I was able to get this working, and clean up a lot of code. thank you very, very much!